# Aborting http request sent via Feign client

Tags: spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-feign

Is there any way to cancel an http request sent via feign client? I thought of intercepting the requests to store them somewhere so I can abort them if needed but there no such method provided by "Request" class. I want to abort file download.

Comment: did you find an answer to your question ? I would like to know how to abort HTTP requests when using Feign as well

Comment: unfortunately not, used async-http-client in the end